# Need a sql statement to do upate and insert at the same time

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I need a sql statement, to insert a new row in one database table and update an existing row in another database table based on some conditions.

Is there a way to do this? To insert a row in one table and update a row in another database table in one sql statement?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they are called [Transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/ansi-diff-transactions.html), and are implemented with [`START TRANSACTION and COMMIT/ROLLBACK`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) with something like:

```
START TRANSACTION;
  INSERT INTO ...
  UPDATE table2 SET name='TOTO' WHERE type=1;
COMMIT;
```

**EDIT**

This is not in fact *one* SQL query, but the operation is done atomically - and I think that is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

A single SQL statement allows you to update one table, not several; if that statement is a [`MERGE`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_%28SQL%29) then you can specify insert/update/delete actions but still targeting just the same one target table.

If you just want consistency, use transactions; until a transaction is committed, changes within it are not visible to the outside world.

If you want that a single update (which you cannot control) resulted in a coordinated insert, use an `on update` trigger in the table being updated. The trigger would insert appropriate row(s) into other table(s).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Trigger` to update second table on insert of first table

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible with stored procedures.

Watch this: [Stored procedures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure)